# error on using Boolean in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

Given an array of start-times and end-times, sort them based on the end-times.

Here's what my function description looks like

```
 // sort() - sorts an array of floats returning sorted indices 
 // On return, indx[] is an array of indices such that data[indx[0]], 
 // data[indx[1]], ..., data[indx[len-1]] is data[] in ascending order. 
 // Parameters 
 //    data[] - float array of data to be ordered 
 //    indx[] - int array, same length as data[], to hold indices
 //    len - int specifying the length of data[] and indx[]
```

and here's the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include sched.h

    void sort(float data[], int indx[], int len);

    int main() {

        int indx[NUM_EVENTS];
        int scheduledEvents[NUM_EVENTS];
        int numSched;

        // Sort by event ending times
        sort(endTime, indx, NUM_EVENTS);

        // Call greedy scheduling algorithm
        numSched = sched(startTime, endTime, indx, scheduledEvents, NUM_EVENTS);

        // Display scheduled events
        for (int i = 0; i < numSched; i++)
            printEvent(startTime[scheduledEvents[i]], endTime[scheduledEvents[i]],
            description[scheduledEvents[i]]);

        return 0;
    }
```

> my sorting algorithm inducing a for loop to check out the outputs
>   looks like

```
    void sort(float data[], int indx[], int len){

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            indx[i];
        }
        float smallestIndex;
        bool flag = 1;
        while (flag == 1){
            flag == 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++){
                if (data[indx[i]] > data[indx[i + 1]]){
                    smallestIndex = indx[i + 1];
                    indx[i + 1] = indx[i];`
                    indx[i] = smallestIndex;
                    flag == 1;
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
            cout << data[indx[i]] << endl;
        }
```

> doing do I got an error that looks like
>
> ***> warning C4806: '==' : unsafe operation: no value of type 'bool'
>   promoted to type 'int' can equal the given constant***
>   1>sched.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   printEvent(float,float,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (?printEvent@@YAXMMV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main

Comment: Know the data types you're dealing with. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type You want to be using `true`/`false` or if you prefer deprecated style `0`/`1`. There's no `2`...

Comment: `flag == 2` How could a `bool` ever equal `2`?

Comment: Dude, just sayin', c++ has built-in sort - you can pass the comparison function - just sayin'.

Comment: If you need more than two values, consider using an `enum` type.

Comment: You only ever use two values so you could leave it as a bool and substitute true for 1 and false for 2.

Comment: in doing so i got an error like 1>sched.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl printEvent(float,float,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?printEvent@@YAXMMV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: Reminds me of the old DailyWTF: `enum Bool { True, False, FileNotFound }`

Comment: The "unresolved external symbol" error is a linker error.  It means that `printEvent()` is defined in a DLL or OBJ file, but the compiler doesn't know where to find it.  You need to add it to the build settings ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bool is a type that usually accepts true and false. Internally it is handled as an int. That is why you can assign numeric values to it. However, if you would like to do this, use int.

Also notice that your line with:

```
flag == 2;
```

has no effect. You compare flag to 2 and the result of this comparison (either true or false) is just left in the air. This is not an error but the whole expression does not do anything.

Comment: in doing so i got an error like 1>sched.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl printEvent(float,float,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?printEvent@@YAXMMV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: This error seems somewhat unrelated. It says that there is no implementation for the printEvent function with parameters, (float,float,string). Whether you use flag with int or bool does not change anything here.

Comment: *"Internally it is handled as an int"* - No. `bool` and `int` are somewhat compatible, but how the compiler implements the two data types is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `flag` only ever holds one of two values, so this would work, leaving your other logic (may not be the most efficient), "as is."

```
bool flag = true;
while (flag == true){
    flag = false; // Tentative "stop"
    for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++){
        if (data[indx[i]] > data[indx[i + 1]]){
            smallestIndex = indx[i + 1];
            indx[i + 1] = indx[i];`
            indx[i] = smallestIndex;
            flag = true;  // Keep going.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i do that i get an error like >fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: That must an unrelated problem.  Did it link OK before, when you ignored the warning about the bool?

Answer (score 1):

A bool can only be true or false, it is binary. You can assign 1 or 0 to an int to get the same result as if you had used a bool if you don't want to use a bool.

Also you use == which is to check equivalence. A single = is for assigning a number which it looks like you want to do when,

```
flag == 2;
```

It should be declared and int (or something similar)

```
int flag = 0;

flag = 2
```